# check the column and multiply other of diferents lenghts

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 differents dataframes:

df1

```
    0    1
0  JJEL  0.2
1  JJSP  0.5
```

df

```
     0     1        2      size
0   JJEL  16.0  11.382219   0.0
27  JJEL  36.0  14.726573  48.0
1   JJEL  37.5  14.977400   0.0
3   JJSP  37.5  14.977400   0.0
33  JJSP  41.5  14.977400   1.0
```

I want to compare df1 0 column with df 0column and sum the column 1 df1 to column 1 df, by theirs respective values. I am having dificulty about the differents lenghts.

expected output:

```
       0     1        2     size
0   JJEL  16.2  11.382219   0.0
27  JJEL  36.2  14.726573  48.0
1   JJEL  37.7  14.977400   0.0
3   JJSP  38.0  14.977400   0.0
33  JJSP  42.0  14.977400   1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas has intrinsic data alignment, which means that pandas will try to do all operations using both the dataframe index and column headers aligned.  If you have duplicate indexing then pandas will create a cartesian product which is the desired result in this case.

For exmaple.

```
df = df.set_index('0')
df.add(df2.set_index('0')).fillna(df).reset_index()
# or df.add(df1.set_index('0'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      0     1          2  size
0  JJEL  16.2  11.382219   0.0
1  JJEL  36.2  14.726573  48.0
2  JJEL  37.7  14.977400   0.0
3  JJSP  38.0  14.977400   0.0
4  JJSP  42.0  14.977400   1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `map`

```
df['1'] = df['1'] + df['0'].map(dict(zip(df1['0'],df1['1'])))


#df['1'] + df['0'].map(dict(zip(df1['0'],df1['1'])))
Out[139]: 
0     16.2
27    36.2
1     37.7
3     38.0
33    42.0
dtype: float64
```

Let us try `merge`

```
df = df.merge(df1,on = ['0'])
#Then we have the value in same df 
df['new'] = df['1_x'] + df['1_y']
```

Comment: Nan values for entire column

Comment: @LucasFrancklin it work fine on my side , try to look at your dataframe name ~ df.columns ~

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` df1 to df2 :

```
result = df2['1'] + df2['0'].map(df1.set_index('0')['1'])
```

Assign `result` back to `df2`:

```
df2.assign(**{'1':result})
 
       0     1          2  size
0   JJEL  16.2  11.382219   0.0
27  JJEL  36.2  14.726573  48.0
1   JJEL  37.7  14.977400   0.0
3   JJSP  38.0  14.977400   0.0
33  JJSP  42.0  14.977400   1.0
```